# Time printing seems off

Tags: python

The following should output minutes, right?

```
start = time.time()
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed time:", (end-start)/60, "minutes.")
```

But it print some enormous amount of numbers. Is it in nano seconds for some reason?
Printing start or end yields `1670316387.6682405`.

Comment: No, it's in seconds. When I run your code, I get the output `Elapsed time: 0.0 minutes.`. Check the documentation for `time.time`. It gets you the time passed since the beginning of the epoch in seconds. https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time. That means, that the value that `time.time` gives you is pretty much meaningless for you and only the difference between two `time.time` values is meaningful and gives you the actual time passed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the code either

Comment: If you see something like `2.384185791015625e-07` printed, it's actually very small, because it's of order 10^(-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`time.time` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) it returns the time since epoch in seconds as float. But

> Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, *not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second*.

To get to minutes/seconds you could format the output and limit to float with two decimals (`:.2f`):

```
print("Elapsed time:", f'{(end - start) / 60:.2f}', "minutes.")
```